# liferay service builder clean and rebuild

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

I have a service builder module whose table definitions need to be changed. In my case I've modified the `portlet-model-hints.xml` file in the service's `/src/main/resources` directory to increase the length of a `String` field from 75 to a higher number. When I run `blade gw cleanServiceBuilder`, the old tables are dropped. When I then run `blade gw buildService` and then deploy the module with `blade deploy`, the new sql scripts are not executed (or something similar -- I can't find the new tables in my database). Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be fixed by manually deleting some rows in the `servicecomponent` and `release_` tables. In particular, after cleaning the service builder, the `servicecomponent` table will still have a row with the service's `buildNamespace` and `buildNumber`. In the `release_` there will be a row with `servletContextName` and `schemaVersion` of the module in question. These two rows can be deleted by hand and the next deploy will create the new tables.

Comment: The proper procedure is to increase the module version and create an upgrade class instead of manipulating the database. Of course, this is if your code is in production. if its on dev...

Comment: It's in development, not production.